# How to change an output variable in a form

Tags: django, forms, overriding

I want to get the `user`, when someone is posting a File.
It, works somehow, but still displays an error.

I tried already to override the `form_valid` , but I always get a `TypeError`.

```
#forms.py
class CreateMemesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meme
        exclude = ["author"]

#models.py
class Meme(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to="memes")

#views.py
class UploadMemes(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = CreateMemesForm
    template_name = "memes/meme_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
#error i get
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

It should get the author as `CustomUser` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line is where the problem is

```
return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

you need to pass the `class name` else blank if you are using `python3`

```
item = self.object.save()
self.pk = item.pk

return super().form_valid(form)
```

then in any function within the view

use `self.pk`

Comment: yea i tryed that but than i dont know how to redirect to a DetailView.

Comment: add `get_success_url` function to redirect to your desired view

Comment: last question: How do i get the pk of the object i just create?

Comment: I have **super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type** and it comes from `def form_valid(self, form):`, using `return super(myForm, self).form_valid(form)`.